# multiple preg_replace on the same variable

Tags: php

While delving into some old code I've stumbled upon a function which is used to clean up special characters using [`preg_replace`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) very excessively. Unfortunatly there's no way to avoid this cleanup, the messed up data arrive from outside.

```
/* Example 1: current code */
$item = preg_replace('/' . chr(196) . '/',chr(142),$item);
$item = preg_replace('/' . chr(214) . '/',chr(153),$item);
$item = preg_replace('/' . chr(220) . '/',chr(154),$item);
```

Alot of those lines are in there, and all do the same (using different characters), so there should be a better way to do this. My first iteration to optimize this would be to use an indexed array, like this:

```
/* Example 2: slightly optimized code */
$patterns = array();
$patterns[0] = '/'.chr(196).'/'; 
$patterns[1] = '/'.chr(214).'/';
$patterns[2] = '/'.chr(220).'/';

$reps = array();
$reps[0] = chr(142); 
$reps[1] = chr(153);
$reps[2] = chr(154);

$item = preg_replace($patterns,$reps,$item);
```

*It does the job*, but I guess there's somewhere a better and/or faster way of doing this alot easier and smarter - maybe even without preg_replace. Due to the early morning and/or the lack of good coffee, I was unable to find it myself so far.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as you're concerned to replace characters, you can make use of [`strtr`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) which has a nice array parameter:

```
$map = array(
  chr(196) => chr(142), 
  chr(214) => chr(153),
  chr(220) => chr(154),
);

$item = strtr($item, $map);
```

Comment: This is by far the cleanest solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I think you could use `str_replace` for this use. Not sure about the characters you're replacing tho. But if `str_replace` works, it'll be a lot faster than those `preg_replace`.

But, does those lines slow your application too much or is it just a case of seeing something you could clean up? Because if it is, don't forget to prepare enough tests to avoid creating problems.

Comment: Aye, it is just a case of seeing something which can be cleaned up. Performance really isn't the issue here (at least not at the moment). And yes, I did prepare some tests before starting this.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `strtr` here.

```
$item = strtr($item, chr(196) . chr(214), chr(142) . chr(153));
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php

Answer (score 1):

You need not regexp to this operation(replacing constant string to another), `str_replace` enough for you here. Besides, `str_replace` allows to replace array by array as you want

Answer (score 1):

`preg_replace` or `str_replace` will both be slower than `strtr` which is designed for exactly this purpose.

```
echo strtr("This is a test","aiu","AIU");
```

will give

```
ThIs Is A test
```