# PHP read file contents and replace text

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter, str-replace

I'm using `codeigniter` as a framework and I want to open a file and return contents as a string then replace some texts.

I'm using the `read_file()` of `codeigniter` to return the file's content as string. I'll be replacing a lot of texts in that template though, so it might be cumbersome to do a `str_replace()` or `regex()`.

The file would be an html template though.

Ex: html_template.php

```
<html>
<body>
   Name : {{name}}<br />
   Email: {{email}}<br />
   Address: {{address}}
</body>
</html>
```

I need to replace `{{name}}`, `{{email}}`, `{{addres}}` on the template with values. So the return string should look like:

```
<html>
<body>
   Name : John Smith<br />
   Email: john.smith@example.com<br />
   Address: somewhere
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10106052/replace-multiple-placeholders-with-php?rq=1

Comment: did you check the template parser in codeigniter userguide ? http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/parser.html