# Replace with same named PHP variable

Tags: php, regex, variables, preg-replace, preg-replace-callback

My Example:

```
$name = "Simon";
$string = "My name is [name].";
echo preg_replace("/\[(.*)]/", ${"$1"}, $string);
// Expected: My name is Simon.
// I get: My name is .
// ${"$1"} should be $name?
exit();
```

When I do only:

```
echo preg_replace("/\[(.*)]/", "$1", $string);
// I get: My name is name.
// $1 = name
```

What am i doing wrong? Why is PHP not using the generated $name var?
This is only a example. I would like to work this with any replace:

```
[foo] --> $foo
[bar] --> $bar
...
```

Comment: echo str_replace("[name]",$name,$string);

Comment: Hey Asik, i don't want to use str_replace because i want to do it with much more vars. I want to work this with any replace. `[foo] > $foo`, `[bar] > $bar`, etc.. I don't want to use arrays.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you're wanting to use `preg_replace()` etc. and not just `$string = "My name is " .$name;`? This sounds like overkill if you just want to echo out/populate a username.

Comment: Explanation is not clear. And lot of edits...?

Comment: I have much more Placeholders, not only [name]. I could put them all in arrays and do str_replace(). It seems for me that the automatic preg_replace() with `$1` would be the more elegant solution.

Comment: In order for this to work, you will need to change `[name]` to `[$name]` and `${"$1"}` to `"$1"`. Least, from what I could gather. Otherwise, you will need to modify something. If you can live with that, great.

Comment: Fred -ii- this is great man, you can post this as an answer. But why is this `${"$1"}` not working? Do you have any clue where's the problem for PHP?

Comment: @user2987790 Because, you already have one `$`.

Comment: @user2987790 It has been done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per OP's wish to post my comment as an answer:

In order for this to work, you will need to change `[name]` to `[$name]` and `${"$1"}` to `"$1"`

```
$name = "Simon";
$string = "My name is [$name].";

echo preg_replace("/\[(.*?)]/", "$1", $string);
```

PHP needs a variable to go on, so using `[name]` isn't being populated.

---

As per [**another and earlier comment**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27046192/replace-with-same-named-php-variable/27046813?noredirect=1#comment42610960_27046192) I made, alternatively you could very well do:

```
$name = "Simon";
$string = "My name is " .$name;

echo $string;
```

If you have a framework with existing brackets, then that is something you haven't told us, only that you said in comments:
*" have much more Placeholders, not only `[name]`"*, whether it's part of something bigger, then stick to the accepted method.

---

As per in comments, you could alternatively use `"/\[([^\]]+)\]/"` instead of `"/\[(.*)]/"`
Or "/[(.*?)]/" :)

in regards to using for example: `"[$foo]bar[$foo]"`

Comment: What's with the dv's?

Comment: If I explained it badly/wrongly, I will adjust my answer.

Comment: `preg_replace` to remove squares? seriously?

Comment: @vp_arth I know, but that's what the OP seems to want to use. There's probably a reason for it, am sure. I asked, but OP didn't respond as to why. As per [**this comment**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27046192/replace-with-same-named-php-variable#comment42610960_27046192)

Comment: you should ungreed it first. `"[$name]text[$name]"` -> `"$name"` now

Comment: @vp_arth Oh, seems OP did respond with [**this comment**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27046192/replace-with-same-named-php-variable#comment42611254_27046192)

Comment: @vp_arth OP has the option.

Comment: no, he uses var_names anyway - so php already has this placeholders - `"{$var}"`

Comment: @vp_arth Exactly and I agree with you.

Comment: fix a bug with greedy

Comment: @vp_arth You could edit your answer with that, I would be glad to upvote it.

Comment: Your answer is totally incorrect now... should be `"/\[([^\]]+)\]/"` or `"/\[(.*?)\]/"`.

Comment: @vp_arth How can it be totally incorrect, I've tested it with `"/\[(.*)]/"` and it worked fine.

Comment: try to test with `"[$foo]bar[$foo]"` :)

Comment: @vp_arth Both methods work, I tested them now. Same result. I could make an edit to that effect, but again, same result. OP is happy with it. :)

Comment: `php -r 'echo preg_replace("/\[(.*)]/", "$1", "[foo]aasdf[foo]");'` Result: `foo]aasdf[foo`

Comment: `OP is happy` is not a SO target. `There is new useful QA` is a target.

Comment: @vp_arth Would you rather I delete my answer? I would be happy to.

Comment: No, just add a question mark to your regular, it's incorrect

Comment: @vp_arth If you have editing privileges, please feel free. I have to go to work now.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use something like this:

```
class Tpl {
  private $tpl;
  public function __construct($tpl) {
     $this->tpl = $tpl;
  }
  public function render($data) {
    $result = $this->tpl;
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
      $result = str_replace("%%$key%%", str_replace('%%', '', $value), $result);
    }
    return $result;
  }
}

$greet = new Tpl('Hello, %%name%%');
echo $greet->render(array('name' => 'World'));
```

But you always must care, that you correctly escape your placeholder formatting.
I just remove it :)

Comment: Finally i formatted the vars in mysql with placeholders {{FOO}} and used [strtr()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10106052/replace-multiple-placeholders-with-php). Thank You All for Your Help! So there is no possibility to store "real" php Vars mixed with Text in mysql? I understand it from the point of security issues but there should be and option to to this.

Answer (score 0):

No need in `preg_replace` at all.
You use variable_names anyway - so php already has this placeholders - `"{$var}"`:

```
$name = "Simon";
$string = "My name is {$name}.";
```

Comment: That's what [**I wrote**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27046192/replace-with-same-named-php-variable#comment42610960_27046192) but the OP seems to want to use that for a particular reason. Why, I have no idea.

Comment: in a mysql field i store text mixed with PHP Vars: `bla $foo bla $bar`. If i store this mysql result and echo it i get the same: `bla $foo bla $bar`. if i store text with placeholders `[foo], [bar]` and change them later to $PHPVars the result should be `bla FOOVAR-CONTENT bla BARVAR-CONTENT` (Before i echo the mysql the vars are already set in the script)

Comment: So the OP did have a "special" reason ;)

Comment: So whats should i do instead? I want to get the already set values of the vars into my mysql-result ?

Comment: No reason... no any profit... no difference from `a {$v} b {$v}` to `a [v] b [v]` if you need `$v` variable to make it works...

Comment: Why your database knows about PHP anything? It's about data, not about implementation.

Comment: PHP gets a mysql-Result like `$mailbody = "Hello $name";`. `$name` is defined before mysql-request. if i echo `$mailbody` my result is still `"Hello $name"` instead of `"Hello MAILBODYCONTENT"`. When i do it the way with placeholders it works..